# Sending HTTP request from Google Apps Script to a website which uses Google sign-in

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-signin

I'm looking to use UrlFetchApp from a code in Google Apps Script to send HTTP requests (GET & POST) to a website which uses Google sign-on. And the Google account is same as that used by the Google apps script.

Is this possible? If yes, how safe is it? Does the website get to see my Google account credentials?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible depending of what these Get and Post function are going to do. Regarding the security issues, if it's a trusted website you shouldn't worry about it. Google [does not share](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/112802?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#basic-info-sharing) your login credentials with any external site, but it's possible it will share your name, email and profile picture. Have you tried any code?

Comment: Hello @Jescanellas apologies couldn't respond earlier. Google sharing my login credentials is not the problem actually. I'm just worried the apps script would need to share the credentials with the website, when trying to login and fetch the data. 

Could you elaborate on how to log into the website from the apps script, given the Google login requirement? That would provide more clarity I believe.